# Is there an alternative to using a cross join in SQL query here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `Person_Gaps` and `MissingDates` where I need to generate a new table `Output` which is all rows combined with person ID and the individual days that they are missing from the `MissingDates` table based on their gap ranges in `Person_Gaps`. Table examples as such:

**Person_Gaps**

```
PersonId  StartDate   EndDate
1         2011-01-01  2011-04-01
1         2014-12-31  2015-05-03
2         2011-01-01  2011-02-01
3         2015-01-01  2015-05-03
.
.
```

**MissingDates**

```
DateVal
2011-01-01
2011-01-02
2011-01-03
.
.
.
2016-01-03
```

**Desired Output Table**

```
PersonID DateVal
1        2011-01-01   
1        2011-01-02
.        .
.        .
2        2011-01-01
2        2011-01-02
3        2015-01-01
3        2015-01-02
.        .
.        .
3        2015-05-03
```

I'm able to get the output I want currently with the following `SELECT` statement using `CROSS JOIN` but I am wondering if there's a better way to do this without the cross join in T-SQL. Perhaps using BETWEEN or the date ranges somehow.

```
SELECT p.PersonID, md.DateVal
FROM Person p
CROSS JOIN MissingDates md
WHERE md.DateVal >= p.StartDate AND md.DateVal <= p.EndDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine.  It can be written using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.PersonID, md.DateVal
FROM Person p JOIN
     MissingDates md
     ON md.DateVal >= p.StartDate AND md.DateVal <= p.EndDate;
```

Your results suggest that you want equality.

Note:  The above is going to generate the same execution plan as your query.  It gets rid of the `CROSS JOIN`, but that will probably not affect performance.